# Stratified box plots in R- Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (21): lower Backtrace:

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to make a stratified box plot in r. Each box plot I would like colored based on variable p (Sally, Tom, Brian). Variable z is the standard deviation I would like to use to define the parameters of each box plot.

Here is a dataframe I call stats4.

```
x   y   z   p
Apple   -2.01742821 0.854645    Sally
Banana  -2.40961853 0.9351938   Sally
Pear    -2.54251787 0.8107368   Sally
Peach   -1.93362529 0.4759018   Sally
Corn    0.19633445  0.7703566   Tom
Spinach -0.65693639 0.4721016   Tom
Peas    0.0472155   0.5040447   Tom
Celery  -0.98787163 0.4819758   Tom
Peppers -3.24175097 0.7759526   Tom
Beets   -1.43366232 0.9785402   Tom
Corn    0.13667242  0.5333245   Brian
Spinach -0.18352371 0.424314    Brian
Peas    -0.25102148 0.3678158   Brian
Celery  -0.47928046 0.3536606   Brian
Peppers -0.57969259 0.7668746   Brian
Peach   0.07644607  0.583220    Brian
Beets   -0.40214063 0.7543126   Brian
Apple   0.21901529  1.095842    Brian
Pear    -2.20649364 0.5803603   Brian
Banana  -1.95593987 0.7153278   Brian
Peppers:Peach   -2.78760145 0.8612689   Brian
```

When I run this I get an error because the aes(fill) parameter is 3 but the geom_boxplot() is trying to define upper and lower limits of the box plots for 21 data points.

This is the error: "Error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (21): lower"

Here is my sample code that errors:

```
ggplot(stats4,aes(x=x, y=y, fill=p)) + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9")) + xlab("") + ylab(expression("Estimated effect")) +
    geom_boxplot(lower=y-(0.5*z),upper=y+(0.5*z),middle=y,ymin=y-z,ymax=y+z) +
    theme(legend.position="none")+ ylim(-4, 1)  + theme_classic() + geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype="dashed", color = "blue", size=1) +  theme(text = element_text(size = 20)) + coord_flip()
```

This code works but I don't have upper and lower limits of the box plots:

```
ggplot(stats4,aes(x=x, y=y, fill=p)) + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9")) + xlab("") + ylab(expression("Estimated effect")) +
    geom_boxplot() +
    theme(legend.position="none")+ ylim(-4, 1)  + theme_classic() + geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype="dashed", color = "blue", size=1) +  theme(text = element_text(size = 20)) + coord_flip()
```

I would like to have my box plots grouped and colored based on variable p, and the box plots upper and lower limits defined based on standard deviation (variable z) for each sample.

I'm just not sure how to fix this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: The issue is not related to the fill. As the error message is telling you the issue is related to `lower`. One issue with your code is that you did not wrap the mapping inside `aes()`, i.e. try with `geom_boxplot(aes(....))`.

Comment: So I tried this and got the same error: 

`ggplot(stats4) + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9")) + xlab("") + ylab(expression("Estimated effect")) +
    geom_boxplot(lower=y-(0.5*z),upper=y+(0.5*z),middle=y,ymin=y-z,ymax=y+z, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=p)) +
    theme(legend.position="none")+ ylim(-4, 1)  + theme_classic() + geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype="dashed", color = "blue", size=1) +  theme(text = element_text(size = 20)) + coord_flip() 
`

Comment: (: I haven't said you should add `aes(x, y)`. Try `geom_boxplot(aes(lower=y-(0.5*z),upper=y+(0.5*z),middle=y,ymin=y-z,ymax=y+z))`.

Comment: If I change `aes(x=x, y=y, fill=p)' to 'aes(x=x, y=y, fill=x)' (and input 21 color codes), The code will work but they won't be grouped based on p anymore.

Comment: Ahh I see. So when I run `ggplot(stats4, aes(x=x, y=y, fill=p)) + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9")) + xlab("") + ylab(expression("Estimated effect")) +      geom_boxplot(aes(lower=y-(0.5*z),upper=y+(0.5*z),middle=y,ymin=y-z,ymax=y+z)) +     theme(legend.position="none")+ ylim(-4, 1)  + theme_classic() + geom_hline(yintercept=0, linetype="dashed", color = "blue", size=1) +  theme(text = element_text(size = 20)) + coord_flip()  ` The output doesn't have  limits of the box plots. It's like the `lower=y-(0.5*z),upper=y+(0.5*z),middle=y,ymin=y-z,ymax=y+z ` is ignored.

Comment: There was still one missing piece. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue with your code is that you did not wrap the mapping for `geom_boxplot` in `aes()`. Moreover, if you want to draw a boxplot by providing the boxplot stats you have to use `stat="identity"`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(stats4, aes(x = x, fill = p)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9")) +
  geom_boxplot(aes(lower = y - 0.5 * z, upper = y + 0.5 * z, middle = y, ymin = y - z, ymax = y + z), stat = "identity") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed", color = "blue", size = 1) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = expression("Estimated effect")) +
  ylim(-4, 1) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme(text = element_text(size = 20))
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).
#> Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
stats4 <- structure(list(x = c(
  "Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Peach", "Corn",
  "Spinach", "Peas", "Celery", "Peppers", "Beets", "Corn", "Spinach",
  "Peas", "Celery", "Peppers", "Peach", "Beets", "Apple", "Pear",
  "Banana", "Peppers:Peach"
), y = c(
  -2.01742821, -2.40961853, -2.54251787,
  -1.93362529, 0.19633445, -0.65693639, 0.0472155, -0.98787163,
  -3.24175097, -1.43366232, 0.13667242, -0.18352371, -0.25102148,
  -0.47928046, -0.57969259, 0.07644607, -0.40214063, 0.21901529,
  -2.20649364, -1.95593987, -2.78760145
), z = c(
  0.854645, 0.9351938,
  0.8107368, 0.4759018, 0.7703566, 0.4721016, 0.5040447, 0.4819758,
  0.7759526, 0.9785402, 0.5333245, 0.424314, 0.3678158, 0.3536606,
  0.7668746, 0.58322, 0.7543126, 1.095842, 0.5803603, 0.7153278,
  0.8612689
), p = c(
  "Sally", "Sally", "Sally", "Sally", "Tom",
  "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Tom", "Brian", "Brian", "Brian",
  "Brian", "Brian", "Brian", "Brian", "Brian", "Brian", "Brian",
  "Brian"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))
```

Comment: Ahh thank you! That's exactly what I want.